# Unable to install boost from Cygwin in Windows 10

Tags: c++, windows, boost, cygwin, clion

I'm pretty sure I'm doing something stupid here but when I try to go install boost from Cygwin's installer, I only see the -debug and -build options.

[Cygwin Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vDgDe.png)

I'm using the http://mirrors.sonic.net mirror. I switch to this from the default mirror because I thought that might have been the problem.

I know the package isn't getting installed because when I try to load my CMAKE file in clion, it throws and an error saying "Could NOT find Boost (missing: Boost_INCLUDE_DIR graph)".

Heres my CMakeLists.txt code:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)
project(HW_9)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

add_executable(HW_9 main.cpp knuth.txt graph_1.h)

# see https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindBoost.html
find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS graph)

include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR})
# Note: a target should be already defined using 'add_executable' or 'add_library'
target_link_libraries(HW_9 ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
```

Comment: maybe you need to install at list `libboost-devel` ?

Comment: Change `skip` against the libraries you want to install to something else?

Comment: Yes. Install the libboost packages with the same version as the -debug and -build packages.

Comment: It looks like the Cygwin package is deprecated since the last update was in 2018.

Comment: It is not latest version (1.66 vs 1.73 ) but it is NOT deprecated. Package maintainers are volunteers and they could have other priorities than packing all boost releases